# Import custom modules in Amazon Sagemaker Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I want to import a custom module in my jupyter notebook in Sagemaker. Trying the import from Untitled1.ipynb I have tried two different structures. The first one is:

[image]

Inside "package folder" there were the files "cross_validation.py" and "**init**.py". The followings commands have been tried:

```
from package import cross_validation
import package.cross_validation
```

The second one is

[image: emak]

and I have coded  `import cross_validation`

In both cases I get no error at all when importing, but I can't use the class inside the module because I receive the error name `Class_X is not defined`

I also have restarted the notebook, just in case and it still not working. How could I make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `__init__.py` file to your `package` directory to make it a Python package. Then you will be import the modules from the package inside your Jupyter notebook

```
/home/ec2-user/SageMaker
    -- Notebook.ipynb 
    -- mypackage
        -- __init__.py
        -- mymodule.py
```

Contents of Notebook.ipynb

```
from mypackage.mymodule import SomeClass, SomeOtherClass
```

For more details, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker!

Comment: In sagemaker with sparkmagic kernel this doesn't work.

Comment: Is it not possible to import custom modules in sparkmagic kernel?

Answer (score 6):

If you also need to import files from parent directories you can add to the path as such:

```
import os
import sys
module_path = "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/{module_name}"
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

Then you can import as if you were in a **normal python environment** from the root of your project

Answer (score 3):

If you use SageMaker Studio, you need to take care about the path.

In the **notebook of SageMaker Studio**:

`!df -h`, You will see the line:

```
127.0.0.1:/200005  8.0E  1.3G  8.0E   1% /root
```

And `!pwd` will be:

`/root`

It is different from the **bash terminal**:

In bash terminal:

```
df -h
127.0.0.1:/200005  8.0E  1.4G  8.0E   1% /home/sagemaker-user

pwd
/home/sagemaker-user
```

So, the outside file path "/home/sagemaker-user" will be mapped into "/root" in your notebooks under SageMaker Studio.

So, the module path will change:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/root/module_name')
```

The detail information can ref this [link](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/955)

Comment: It works for me.  I had the `/root/username` path and I just added `/root/`. So I can just run `import package.module` or `from package import module`.